# Gradle issues on Android Bumblebee on Mac

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm recently installed Android Studio and create a project and I'm seeing the following gradle issues when trying to build:

```
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2.
         Required by:
             project :
          > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2.
             > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.1.2/gradle-7.1.2.pom'.
                > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.1.2/gradle-7.1.2.pom'.
                   > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
                      > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I installed the gradle-7.1.2.pom as mentioned but there's no information on where to place it.

Also I'm seeing the following gradle error:

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?